# References for web application scalability and deployment best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, web-deployment, unicorn

I find it easy to find resources on amazon/online to learn new frameworks/programming languages. However, when it comes to web app deployment, I find it really hard to find a single resource that explains all. Most of them just tell you what to do without explaining 'why'.

I just did my second rails app deployment with unicorn and nginx. Although I 'kind of' know what is going on when reading the tutorial, I would like to know more about the 'how' and 'why' of the steps that were given.

In short, I would like to read books/articles/tutorials (hopefully all-in-one) about best practices for web app deployment, and how to scale/load-balance your app when it gets more traffic (and hopefully it the tutorial uses NGINX/unicorn setup).

Answer (score 0):

Well, deployment and scaling are completely orthogonal topics, so I don't think you'll find an article/tutorial that covers both.

As for deployment, you better automate your work. When you deploy to 100+ servers, the last thing you want to do is to do it manually (fetch from git, migrate db, restart servers, etc).

1. [Capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano) - very well known and adopted tool for deploying Rails.
2. [Vlad](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html) - another tool that gains more attention lately.
3. [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) - very powerful tool for server management. Several top Russian sites use it.

Comment: i am referring to the first-time set up. assigning the right pport. configuring the nginx.conf and unicorn.rb.

Comment: So, what are the decisions that confuse you?

Comment: when i read tutorials on how to set up server, there is really no explanation to why the configuration is done that way. i want to know what the configuration means and somewhat thorough explanation about them.